# Mixing two records in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to mix two record to make one
for example

```
 ID      Date         UserID1    UserID2
 123     09/01/2015              670
 123     09/01/2015      750
```

Results I want

```
 ID      Date         UserID1    UserID2
 123     09/01/2015     750         670
```

Comment: Please give more info about how and why you want the records to be 'mixed', i.e., the condition for which the records should be mixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  This works for your two records:

```
select id, date, max(userid1) as userid1, max(userid2) as userid2
from table t
group by id, date;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help that was really helpfull